# Creating complete data in stata

Tags: stata

I have the following purchasing data

```
clear 
input id productid purchase
1     1         1
2     1         1
3     2         1
1     3         1
end
```

I want to add a row for every id-productid combo to create the following dataset

```
id productid purchase
1     1         1
2     1         1
3     1         0
1     2         0
2     2         0
3     2         1
1     3         1
2     3         0
3     3         0
end
```

I have tried a lot that has not work. This is my latest.

```
qui sum id, d
local obs = r(N) 
expand = `obs'
levelsof productid, local(id)
local j = 1
foreach i of local id {
    replace productid = `i' if `j' == id
    local j = `j' + 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fillin` command (see `help fillin`) is the tool for this task.

Starting with your sample data in memory:

```
fillin id productid
replace purchase = 0 if _fillin
drop _fillin
sort productid id
list, sepby(productid) abbreviate(12)
```

produces

```
     +---------------------------+
     | id   productid   purchase |
     |---------------------------|
  1. |  1           1          1 |
  2. |  2           1          1 |
  3. |  3           1          0 |
     |---------------------------|
  4. |  1           2          0 |
  5. |  2           2          0 |
  6. |  3           2          1 |
     |---------------------------|
  7. |  1           3          1 |
  8. |  2           3          0 |
  9. |  3           3          0 |
     +---------------------------+
```

Comment: Very helpful. Could i ask you a question? Let's say I have a `start_date` and `end_date` for each `id` and a `date` that the `productid` became available. Is it possible to code fillin to be mindful of those dates. I.e., make it so a person who could not buy a product does not have a row

Comment: In my MWE I did not add some time invariant variables about the individuals. How do I fill in that info for each person in the data

Comment: I would create two new datasets from your original data. (1) the time invariant data, one observation per id (2) the time-varying data without the time invariant data. I would apply `fillin` to the second dataset, then use `merge m:1` to add the time-invariant data back onto the expanded dataset.